# Application fails to run in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest, android-debug

I have coded an application .Everything is fine in the code. But it do not run in the emulator. It give some error as follows:

1. Parser exception for D:\Android Workspace\DbTuts\AndroidManifest.xml: The element type "application" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".
2. No command output when running: 'am start -n com.android.tuts/com.android.tuts.MyActivity -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER' on device emulator-5556

Manifest code is as follows :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.android.tuts"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
 <application android:name=".ApplicationContextProvider"
         android:label="@string/app_name"></application> 

 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

  </application>
  </manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.android.tuts"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

 <application android:name=".ApplicationContextProvider" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

  </application>
  </manifest>
```

You were using two separate `<application>` elements before, which isn't allowed.

Comment: Now it gives a  msg in emulator as 'The application has stopped unexpectedly'.

Comment: The application probably stops due to another error in your code. Post your logcat and the relevant code

Comment: You should accept this answer, and open another question if you still have a problem